# Using shared variables in a Group Name Formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

In Crystal Reports I am trying to use a shared variables in a group name formula.

When I include whileprintingrecords; I get error "The formula cannot be evaluated at the time specified"

When  I remove whileprintingrecords; I get a "A 'shared' variable can only be used while printing records".

Is there a way to use shared variables in a group name formula in Crystal Report?

Comment: It's best to tag your question with 'crystal-reports' and the ONE that represents the version of the product that you are using.

Comment: Why are you using `WhilePrintingRecords`?  Why are you using a `Shared` variable?  Do you have a sub-report?

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is **no**. A shared variable will only contain meaningful data `whileprintingrecords` since this is after the subreports have completed. Grouping, including the Group Name Formula, is evaluated earlier than this so the variable data won't be ready yet at that point in time.

If you explain what you're trying to do a little more and the data you're working with then maybe we can come up with a workaround.